# How do I go to a new path after signing up in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm new to React, I'm building an Electron app.

In the code below, I check to see if there's a signed in user, and if so, I render `Home`, if they haven't logged in yet or signed up, I render `SignIn`

(this code lives in `app.js`)

```
if (JSON.parse(localStorage.cookies).user_id === undefined) {
render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <SignIn />
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('content'));
} else {
    render((
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Home />
        </Provider>
    ), document.getElementById('content'));
}
```

When the user signs up or logs in, I want to take them to `Home` right afterwards. I can do that in development my refreshing my Electron window. How do I achieve this in my code?

Here is the code for `SignIn.js`

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {signUp, logIn} from '../entities/auth/actions';

class SignIn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.logIn = this.logIn.bind(this);
        this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            registration: {
                username: '',
                password: '',
                email: '',
            },
            login: {
                username: '',
                password: '',
            },
        };
    }

    signUp() {
        this.props.dispatch(signUp(this.state.registration));
    }

    logIn() {
        this.props.dispatch(logIn(this.state.login));
    }

    render() {
        const {registration, login} = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="sign-in">
                <h1>MyApp</h1>

                <form id="login-form" onSubmit={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }}>
                    <input type="username" value={login.username} placeholder="Enter username" onChange={e => this.setState({login: {...login, username: e.target.value}})}/>
                    <input type="password" value={login.password} placeholder="Enter password" onChange={e => this.setState({login: {...login, password: e.target.value}})}/>
                    <button onClick={this.logIn}>Log in</button>
                </form>

                <form id="registration-form" onSubmit={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }}>
                    <input type="text" value={registration.username} placeholder="Enter user name" onChange={e => this.setState({registration: {...registration, username: e.target.value}})}/>
                    <input type="password" value={registration.password} placeholder="Enter password" onChange={e => this.setState({registration: {...registration, password: e.target.value}})}/>
                    <input type="email" value={registration.email} placeholder="Enter email" onChange={e => this.setState({registration: {...registration, email: e.target.value}})}/>
                    <button onClick={this.signUp}>Sign up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

SignIn.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func,
};

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    return {};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `localStorage.cookies` being updated correctly?

Comment: Yes because if I do a refresh with my keyboard after signing up, I'm taken to `Home`

Comment: Could you try making the conditional (`if localStorage ...etc`) *inside* the `<Provider>` tag?

Comment: are you using a router at all?

Comment: @BravoZulu I'm not. I don't believe Electron and routers work together but I could be wrong

Comment: Edit: I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to use `react-router`, a way to approach this problem would be to have a higher component that renders either `Login` or `Home` by checking the cookies.  This component could have a state value `loggedIn`. For example:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    const isLoggedIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.cookies).user_id === undefined;
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    }
  }
  handleLogin() {
    //if login was successful, do:
    this.setState({ loggedIn: true })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.loggedIn
          ? <Home />
          : <LoggedIn handleLogin={this.handleLogin}>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then trigger `handleLogin` in your Login component somehow:

```
 signUp() {
        this.props.dispatch(signUp(this.state.registration, this.props.handleLogin));
    }

    logIn() {
        this.props.dispatch(logIn(this.state.login, this.props.handleLogin));
    }

    render() {
        const {registration, login} = this.state;
```

This will update the parent state and rerender the appropriate component.

Also need to change

```
render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Application />
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This was really helpful. One small edit and then I'll accept this answer, I needed to pass in this.props.handleLogin like this `this.props.dispatch(signUp(this.state.registration, this.props.handleLogin));` and then call `action.callback();` in my `/auth/sagas.js` file so that the API call had time to complete, return the value and then set it in localStorage before continuing. Your code as-is calls a re-render before localStorage is set. thanks again

Comment: Updated.  Can you post your saga file? I'm not familiar with the library and i'm interested in how you trigger callbacks